# Looping in SSIS via source tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, ssis, etl

we have a DB server that contains multiple instances of the same database. All databases are enumerated (e.g. MyDB001 to MyDB006). All instances have the same tables.

For reporting purposes we would like to extract all these DBs to a single DB.

Current solution is to have multiple connections in the SSIS - for each DB one dedicate connection. Also there is a data flow per DB to extract the tables. This leads to changing multiple data flows if we would need change the extraction.

Is there a smart way to loop over the database? E.g. use a parameter to get the connection to the DB and then have one dataflows using this parameterized connection to get the data?

Thanks for any hint in advance.

SillyWalker

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. You start with just a data flow with source and destination. click the background in the control flow, properties, change protection level to don't save sensitive.

Click the source connection, properties, copy and paste the connection string to a text editor. still in properties, expression, click the ... then in property expression editor, from property drop box, select connection string, in the expression, you define the connection string and points to the database you want, you can take the connection string you saved to the text editor earlier and modify accordingly, e.g. change to the database you want.

play with it until you understand what above means and you can change connection string expression to point to any source table. after you understand this, you can start the loop part. Add two variables, one is cs (type string), this will be your dynamic database connection string, second one is rs (type object), this will hold the collection of database connections. In control flow, add a execute sql task, a foreach loop container, connect execute sql task to the container, drag and drop the data flow into the container. open the execute sql task, in general tab, sqlstatement, you define your collection of database connections
something like : select val from tabl (tal stores all your database connections in a column val). In resultSet, select Full result set. in result set tab, change Result Name to 0, variable to the variable rs. This will map the collection of database connection strings to the variable rs.

Next double click foreach loop container to edit it. In collection tab, select Foreach ADO Enumerator, in ADO object source variable, select the variable rs.In Variable mapping tab, select cs in Variable, index should be 0.

Now in your data flow, click the source connection, in expression, set connection string to the variable cs. Test and have fun.

The whole picture:

[image]